# Stylesheet refused by browser with wicket and spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot, wicket

I am trying wicket with spring-boot integration and I am trying to simply add a stylesheet to a very simple page. So I placed the stylesheet in `resources/static/css` as usual in Spring-boot and in fact, I see it is served (by pointing to CSS URL).

On the other side, I did not see in the sources (Ctrl+Shift+I in Chrome), so I checked the browser log and found the following error:

```
Refused to load the stylesheet 'http://localhost:8080/css/custom.css' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'none-...."
```

I have **NOT** enabled Spring Security because I am still trying to understand how Wicket works, but if needed I can do it.

Can anybody suggest a solution?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by Wicket's [CSP](https://content-security-policy.com/) (Content Security Policy).

You can  disable it by adding the following line in `YourApplication#init()` method:

```
getCspSettings().blocking().disabled();
```

You will have to read some more about CSP if you want to re-enable it.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was indeed that! I did not expect to block resources from the same origin with Spring security disabled.